# Windows mobile SDK 6.0 GPS sample not worked

Tags: c#, windows, gps, windows-mobile-6

These days I'm try to implement GPS application for windows mobile device. I had try Windows mobile SDK 6.0 sample but unfortunately it doesn't work. I configure GPS ports properly. It just print "On, StartingUp". longitude and latitude and other details are not printed.

Then I had try another third party tool called "GPSTest" to find whether my GPS receiver worked or not. It worked nicely and that means my GPS receiver works fine.

Are there any known issues is WM SDK 6.0 GPS sample ?

How can I fix this issue and print longitude and latitude and other details ?

Thank you ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what comm the WM6 SDK sample uses, but there are three different comm possible with GPS:

a) MS GPS Intermediate Driver (GPSID). If the device is setup correctly you do not need to change any port.

b) Serial communication via a COMx: or similar named port (I saw also GPDx:). This direct communication needs a parsing of the raw NMEA data. Your program also needs to nkow the correct serial port baudrate setting etc Some GPS devices use a binary protocol and you may have to switch the GPS modul to character mode (the switch commend is GPS hardware dependent).

c) Stream communication. You need to know the communication port (i.e. COM6: or GPD1:) and then use file streaming to read either RAW binary or character data from the GPS modul. As with b), your app hase to parse the NMEA data to find longitude, latitude and all the information inside the NMEA protocol.

See here for an example working with MS GPSID and Serial or Stream communication for RAW NMEA data: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/06/11/enhanced-gps-sample-update/

The sample uses MS GPSID and can be switched to also show the raw data comming thru serial or stream port. The port name is determined by using the MS GPSID registry settings.

BTW: the service GPS states are not implemented on all devices and so may show wrong status.